# Display base64 MS Office file content in iOS 10 Safari

Tags: safari, base64, ms-office, ios10, docx

I am showing the Microsoft Office files (doc / docx / ppt / pptx / xls / xlsx) content at iOS Safari with the trick of redirecting browser at

```
data:application/msword;base64,0M8R4KGxGuEAAAA....
```

It worked happily for a few years until iOS 10 went live at last month. pdf and image files still works well in this way with correct MIME type. Any idea to make it work again?